# How do I get a hard line break in a multiline table using markdown

Tags: markdown, line-breaks, pandoc

The [markdown docs claim](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html):

> A backslash followed by a newline is also a hard line break. Note: in
> multiline and grid table cells, this is the only way to create a hard
> line break, since trailing spaces in the cells are ignored.

I have an 2 column table where I could make this work for the last column in the row:

```
-------------------------------------------------
                           35                    
-------------------------- ----------------------
**0-6 mon**                1                    \
                           0.5                  \
                           0                    \
                           0                    \
                           0                     
                           
-------------------------------------------------
```

However, when I try to do it for two columns in a row, it fails.  If I do it like this, it makes a table, but only puts hard breaks on the last column:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            35                     35-45                
-------------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
**0-6 mon**                1                                           \
                           0.5                                         \
                           0                                           \
                           0                                           \
                           0                      3                    \
                                                  13                   \
                                                  0                    \
                                                  0.02                 \
                                                  0                     

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I do it like this, it doesn't consider it a valid table:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            35                     35-45                
-------------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
**0-6 mon**                1                    \
                           0.5                  \
                           0                    \
                           0                    \
                           0                      3                    \
                                                  13                   \
                                                  0                    \
                                                  0.02                 \
                                                  0                     

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Has anyone ever got this to work?

The answer appears to be: you can not do this with a "multiline" table, only with a grid table.  The question marked as a potential duplicate was asking about how to do this in HTML, my question is how to do this so it will work for any output format.

Comment: That question was focused on HTML output.  Mine needs to work with Word output.  Until @mb21 came along, did not address my issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Pandoc you can use [grid tables](http://pandoc.org/README.html#extension-grid_tables):

```
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Fruit         | Price         | Advantages         |
+===============+===============+====================+
| Bananas       | first line\   | first line\        |
|               | next line     | next line          |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Bananas       | first line\   | first line\        |
|               | next line     | next line          |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: This seems to work also for other table types, e.g. `simple_tables` and `mutiline_tables`.